# How to turn on Hardware texturing using python?

Tags: python, maya

I know in MEL, to do this you have to do

```
modelEditor -e -displayTextures true modelPanel4;
```

What would I do in python to get the same exact result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmds.modelEditor('modelPanel4', e=True, displayTextures=True)
```

more help of the command at :
https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2008help/CommandsPython/modelEditor.html